# Are there countries that ban public sector unions, but allow private sector ones?

Tags: labor-union, public-administration

A new initiative is currently [being proposed](https://news.ballotpedia.org/2021/08/13/union-station-proposed-california-initiative-would-ban-public-sector-unions/) in California:

> On Aug. 9, 2021, venture capitalist Timothy Draper filed a proposal
> with the California attorney general’s office for an initiated
> constitutional amendment that would prohibit public-sector workers
> from forming unions. If supporters gather enough valid signatures, it
> will appear on the Nov. 8, 2022, ballot.

Are there countries/states that ban public sector employees from forming a union, but still allow private sector employees to form one? Or would California be the first such states if this initiative manages to pass?

Comment: It seems like that would violate both federal law and the federal constitution.

Comment: @Accumulation there’s existing precedent saying it wouldn’t: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatch_Act_of_1939#Provisions

Comment: I don't see what relevance you think that has. Ctrl-f on "unions" yielded only one result: "In 1976, Democrats who controlled Congress had sought to win support by adding protections against the coercion of employees by their superiors and federal employee unions had supported the legislation."

Comment: @Accumulation you misunderstand - the Hatch act was found constitutional despite violating the 1st Amendment. The Court ruled that restricting the freedom of speech and association of government employees has merit. Same would apply here. Plus as described in answers below, North Carolina and South Carolina have a similar law on the books that was never challenged.

Comment: If it was found to violate the first amendment, then it follows that it was unconstitutional. Perhaps you mean "It was found to be constitutional despite restricting speech". The answer below discusses specific union activities that are banned, and while that may *effectively* be a ban on unions, at outright ban on unions would almost certainly be found to be unconstitutional. The proposed ban you link to is extremely broad, and taken literally could be interpreted as banning headhunters, employment law firms, etc. Not that it has any chance of passing anyway.

Comment: Apparently that prop failed to even gather enough support/signatures to be on the ballot https://ballotpedia.org/California_Prohibit_Public_Sector_Unions_Initiative_(2022)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In North Carolina, while I believe public-sector unions are not *technically* illegal, it is illegal for them to either strike *or* collectively bargain with any branch of the state government or its constituent local governments. This means that public sector unions are more or less *de facto* banned in the state. I understand the law is similar in South Carolina. [Virginia also had](https://www.johnlocke.org/update/the-case-against-public-sector-collective-bargaining/) a similar law prior to 2021, but it was since repealed.

Sources:
[Freshmen state legislators want to overturn law that has held back unions for 60 years](https://www.newsobserver.com/news/local/article229597039.html)
[Article 12: Units of Government and Labor Unions, Trade Unions, and Labor Organizations, and Public
Employee Strikes.](https://www.ncleg.net/EnactedLegislation/Statutes/PDF/ByArticle/Chapter_95/Article_12.pdf)

Comment: Interestingly it looks like the union ban did help North Carolina's budget as their pensions are [funded at 96%](https://graphics.wsj.com/table/Connecticut_102015) while it didn't help South Carolina where pensions are only funded to 63%. Seems like a public union ban alone wouldn't resolve the issue.

Comment: What exactly are the North Carolina public sector unions permitted to do then?

Comment: @user2617804 An excellent question. As in the days before unions were even legal, or had been institutionalized in any way, they are able to organize outside the context of the legal framework of formal strikes and negotiated contracts. For example, rather than repeated strikes, they may hold repeated "sick-outs" (everyone calls in "sick" at the same time, halting work) until the city/county/state passes a wage increase.

Answer (score 37):

Arguably this somewhat depends on where you draw the line between a public sector employee and a civil servant. There may or may not be a difference between the two classes in your jurisdiction. In Germany, there is.

German law distinguishes between public sector *employees* (*Angestellte* im öffentlichen Dienst) and *civil servants* (*Beamte*). The former are regular employees as they would be in the private sector with the exception that their employer is the state or federal government or a municipality or local council. In general (but not always), these are the lower-paying positions. They enjoy the same rights as private sector employees, including the right to join or form a union and to go on strike for better pay. Possibly the most visible of these would be employees in public transport (bus or tram drivers) which are typically employed by a city or regional-government-owned company, often represented by the union Verdi and cause national headlines when they go on strike every two or so years.

On the other hand, there are civil servants. Unlike public sector employees, they swear an oath to uphold the constitution on their appointment. There are a number of differences in terminology (e.g. public sector employees receive a salary called *Gehalt* while for civil servants it is called *Sold* or *Besoldung*) but also important differences in their rights and obligations. Most notably (especially in the context of the question), civil servants cannot be dismissed but also cannot go on strike or form unions. Instead, their salary and working hours are determined by law (but tend to follow the development negotiated by public sector employees and their unions).

It should be noted that some positions can be employees first and transformed into civil servants later. For example, teachers are typically employees at the beginning of their career and become *verbeamtet* later.

Whether or not this example meets your criteria obviously depends on the line you drew above.

Comment: *"In general, these [public sector employees] are the lower-paying positions"* Well, I am a *Angestellter im öffentlichen Dienst* (software developer in a government-owned company) and I make more money than a *Beamter* in a middle-management position. The paygrades for *Beamte* and *Angestellte* on comparable positions are actually pretty similar.

Comment: This is a very good point. The reason *police* unions are considered dangerous is because, well, police are dangerous. A bus driver's union strike could cause disruption, but so could any other union for private employees.

Comment: Note that this doesn't mean public servants can't form a union, it just prevents them from doing things unions do, for example, going on strike. The police have their "representation organization" called "Gewerkschaft der Polizei", which literally translates to "union of the police". They're not completely toothless either; while they can't start a strike, they can suggest to their members to do "Dienst nach Vorschrift" - "work to rule" - don't break any rules, but don't be any more enthusiastic than you have to be. Which, depending on the position, does not feel very different from a strike.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm interesting, sounds like they *do* have unions in all but name and thus are subject to the same conflict of interest as all other public sector unions.

Comment: @JonathanReez not "in all but name". They have unions period. "Gewerkschaft" ist the exact word that unions for the private sector usw. It's just that they cannot strike under any circumstances (neither the individuals nor can the union call for a strike)

Comment: @JonathanReez They have unions (including the name), but the unions for state officers don't negotiate the pay or work conditions, nor can they strike.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't know if any western liberal democracies could do anything to forbid such behaviours without plainly violating the freedom of association and speech. If you consider a union without mandatory membership nor ability to strike nor legal right to negociate with an employer a union for the purpose of your question simply because they can suggest to their members to work to rule, then the only way to outlaw that would be either banning civil servants from forming an association with their collegues or banning an association from advocating a legal activity.

Comment: @xngtng the proposed California amendment would indeed restrict any organization who's purpose is negotiate around working conditions. Since it would only apply to government workers, I presume it might hold its ground in court if it ever passes. The main problems with public sector unions is that they can influence the government to increase their wages/pensions, while also being immune from their employer going bankrupt as a result. Its the root cause of the fiscal crisis in many US states.

Comment: @JonathanReez Ban on collective bargaining or government refusing to recognize an employee association is one thing. But I don't see how the Court could on one hand enforce right to work in *Janus* because labour relations are of public concern, and on the other hand not apply first amendment protection to the activites proposed to be banned by the amendment.

Comment: @xngtng the Supreme Court [ruled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatch_Act_of_1939#Provisions) that certain 1st Amendment restrictions for government employees are acceptable.

Comment: @JonathanReez The California proposal does not appear to bar associations of government employees. At least by US standards, the German entities you consider “unions in all but name” are not remotely an actual union. The core things a union does are collectively bargain with the employer on behalf of employees, and formally represent employees to the employer. Without either of those things, you don’t have a union. The [proposed amendment](https://oag.ca.gov/system/files/initiatives/pdfs/21-0008A1%20%28Public%20Employee%20Labor%20Organizations%20%29_1.pdf) only bans collective bargaining.

Comment: @Philipp there is always overlap, you're part of that overlap :) We see the same in the Netherlands. Garbage collectors are employees and HR clerks are civil servants. Somewhere in between the two must be some group that's mixed, somewhere where the lines overlap.

Answer (score 13):

There are many U.S. jurisdictions in which some public sector employees cannot unionize, and in the U.S. the right of most kinds of private sector employees who aren't part of management (although not all) to unionize, is secured by federal law (the National Labor Relations Act). Unsurprisingly, unionization of federal government employees is also governed by federal law.

Management workers in both government and the private sector are not generally permitted to unionize (including almost all government lawyers and judges and all military personnel, for what it is worth).

Federal law (other than the U.S. Constitution) does not apply to public sector unionization at the state and local level in the U.S., for federalism reasons.

Wikipedia reviews [the relevant U.S. history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-sector_trade_unions_in_the_United_States). Postal service unions first arose in 1890 and have persisted to the present. Other public service unions emerged, such as the Boston Police Union, but a strike by that union in 1919 resulted in the elimination of public sector unionization in the U.S. (outside public schools and the post office) from 1919 to 1958. Public sector unions in the U.S. have expanded rapidly since then. Federal government unions outside the postal service were legalized in 1962.

> In 2010 8.4 million government workers were represented by unions,
> including 31% of federal workers, 35% of state workers and 46% of
> local workers.

[In the United States in the year 2020](https://www.bls.gov/opub/ted/2021/a-look-at-union-membership-rates-across-industries-in-2020.htm):

> The union membership rate (the percentage of wage and salary workers
> who were members of unions) was 10.8 percent. . . .
> the union membership rate in the public sector . . . [was] 34.8
> percent, while the rate in the private sector . . . [was] 6.3 percent.

Public sector unions typically afford a different mix of benefits for members than a typical private sector union does.

Public sector workers have had many union-like benefits such as defined benefit pension plans and the right to be fired only for cause (two of the main goals of many private sector unions), for much longer than public sector unions have been widespread. The federal civil service system was begun [in 1883](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_federal_civil_service#:%7E:text=The%20United%20States%20Civil%20Service,the%20United%20States%20federal%20government.) in reaction to abuses of political patronage by prior administrations, especially that of President Andrew Jackson.

There continue to be many cases in the U.S. where government workers can unionize, but not strike, either due to a global rule that applies to every unionized government workplace of that type in that jurisdiction, or due to a widely adopted collective bargaining agreement term.

For example, [unionized federal government employees don't have the right to strike](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/5/7311), as a matter of federal statutory law.

**Some Brief Comparative Observations About Private Sector Unions**

What a union does and means varies from country to country.

For example, the main kind of private sector union in Japan, which is sponsored by the company itself, is prohibited under the National Labor Relations Act in the United States.

Similarly, while U.S. unions are organized primarily on an employer by employer basis (with a few notable exceptions like people in the live theater, TV and film industries), some countries have unions organized on an industry by industry basis.

Private sector unionization in the U.S., in contrast to public sector unionization, has declined more or less steadily since about 1970, mostly due to outsourcing and off shoring that is not feasible for many kinds of government workers (a full analysis of that point is beyond the scope of this question).

Answer (score 9):

Historically, this was in fact exactly the situation in France between 1884 (loi Waldeck-Rousseau, which made trade unions legal again) and 1946 (when it became legal for low-level civil servants to form a union). Since then, union rights for public sector employees have been strengthened (it's anchored in the most recent constitution and in international law and the law now provides for specific resources to make that right effective) but California would therefore not be the “first” jurisdiction to make that kind of distinction.

Note that, perhaps against some clichés, France has a rather low unionization rate ([one of the lowest in the OECD](https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=TUD), similar to the US), whether in the public or in the private sector.

Comment: "Public sector employees tend to be more unionised than those in the private sector, with 19,1% in the public sector belonging to a union compared to 8,4% of their private counterparts" compared to 34.8% and 6.3% respectively, in the U.S. https://www.thelocal.fr/20190920/five-things-you-need-to-know-about-trade-unions-in-france/ But French unions (especially in the public sector) have more power than comparable U.S. unions do. The overall rate is France is 11% which is about the same as the U.S.

Comment: @ohwilleke public unions (at least teacher ones) have vast powers in the US thanks to a long history of being the backbone of the Democratic Party. The California amendment is primarily a result of backlash to them successfully sabotaging the reopening of schools in many states.

Comment: @ohwilleke I was mostly thinking about comparable (Western) European countries, not the US. French unions (in some sectors) do have a broader base and ability to mobilise workers that go well beyond membership numbers, all of which might partly be a result from this long history of hostility towards unions.

Comment: @JonathanReez As noted, public sector unions often can't strike in governmental functions where French ones can. Lots of conduct that is sometimes tolerated from French unions (like kidnapping a private sector CEO) would be harshly put down in the U.S. The details would take a law review article to spell out in detail. Dems used to be mostly private sector union based, the public sector union support has flowed from the overall decline in private sector and rise in public sector unionization in the last few decades.

Comment: @ohwilleke In most cases, it's the local management or the director of a facility belonging to a larger concern who is being “detained”, rarely the CEO and I have never heard of anyone being kidnapped (in the sense of being transported somewhere they weren't already). At the end of the day, the actual sentence is often very light or nonexistent but such “detention” is still illegal and prosecuted. Perpatrors are sometimes (but not exclusively or mainly) union members or leaders but it's not exactly something the union as such unambiguously condones.

Comment: French unions also cannot strike, that makes no sense. Individuals can go on strike (or not, depending on their status, e.g. military). No need to be a member of a union. Unions can organise or push for a strike obviously but it's also a decision that is taken outside of the union and its success depends on the unions' ability to convince non-union members. As I said, membership is typically low and on top of that, much more divided that nearly everywhere else, it's not unusual to have 4 or 5 different unions for a given business.

Comment: It's a mistake to think labor conflicts or spectacular actions like mass protests or detention (which are real) reflect the strength of the French union movement or a positive attitude of the French state towards unions. The exact opposite is true.

Comment: @Relaxed IMHO the proper measure of union power is what a union is able to accomplish in practice. It certainly appears to me that French unions are much more effective in that regard than American unions, which in the private sector particularly have never had fewer members, and overall have engaged in fewer labor actions (weighted by duration and number of workers) relative to the size of the labor force than any time in history including time periods where labor unions were undoubtedly illegal and considered criminal enterprises.